# running ten thread for each ten items in my array each time

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, for-loop

I have an array, for example 100 items and I want to run 10 thread for each 10 items of my array.

My problem is that I do not know how can I use a for loop to run 10 thread for first 10 item, second 10 item and etc.

What I need is like below:

```
for item in myarray:
    thread.start_new_thread(first_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(second_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(third_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(fourth_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(fifth_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(sixth_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(seventh_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(eight_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(ninth_item)
    thread.start_new_thread(tenth_item)
```

and for second round of my for loop, run the threads for second ten items.

How can I increase my index of my for loop ten times each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is questionable design because:

- you start a new thread for each item instead  of re-using them (thread creation is expensive)
- you do not explain how you want to synchronize the threads to limit their number to ten (do you really want to wait for the first bunch of 10 threads to finish to start ten more?)

The common way is to use a pool of threads. You could search `concurrent.futures` for Python 3.2+, or in older version (not too old either...) `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Comment: Thank you @Serge, I completely confused. I just want to speed up my program, but this is my first time I want to use threads in my program. I think concurrent.futures is a little complex for me to understand :)